# Как вывести следующий по списку элемент?

Tags: python, list, список, индексация

Допустим,у нас есть список по типу:

```
my_list = ['o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd']
```

При вводе в консоль символа `o`,нужно,чтобы программа выдавала последующий символ `p`.
Нужна возможность вывода для всех элементов списка,а не для конкретно `o`.
Список может состоять из **1000000000** символов,так что банальный перебор для каждого элемента не подойдёт!

Comment: `indexOf + 1`.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = ['o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd']

char = input()

try:
    index_char = my_list.index(char)
except:
    next_char = ''
else:
    if index_char == len(my_list)-1:
        next_char = ''
    else:
        next_char = my_list[index_char+1]

print(next_char)
```

пример работы:

```
>? s
d
```

Comment: Как мне кажется, секция `else:` здесь лишняя. Если уж используется `try` то всё тупо можно дать на откуп ему: `try: next_char = my_list[my_list.index(char)+1]       except: next_char = None`